# Table within a table, table outputted except last <td> in each row except for the first row?

Tags: php, html-table, nested-loops

I've got an inventory table that needs to have certain in each row, and then in the last column in each row, i want to loop out each item that was used per a specific inventory update i.e.

one row would have one column for the customername, one column for the date of the inventory transaction, one for the type of transaction, the specific technician and the last column for the certain products that were used in the update. what i've got so far loops out the first 4 columns fine, but the last column only gets generated for the first row. code:

```
<table style="width:92%;">
              <tr style="font-size:14px;">
                <th style="width:150px;">Customer</th>
                <th style="width:110px;">Date</th>
                <th style="width:140px;">Tech</th>
                <th style="width:50px;text-align:center;">Type</th>
                <th>Equipment</th>
              </tr>
              <?php
                $pd_name = array();
                $compArray = array();
                $prevCompany = '';
                $count = 0;
                $select = mysql_query("SELECT pd_name, pd_col_name, company FROM item_inventory ORDER BY company ");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
                    $pd_name[$row['pd_col_name']] = $row['pd_name'];
                    $compArray[$row['pd_col_name']] = $row['company'];
                }

                $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tech_inventory WHERE date >= '$date%' ORDER BY date DESC ");
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2)){ 
                    $count = 0;
                    $prevCompany = '';
                ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2['customerName']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row2['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row2['tech']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row2['type']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <table width="200">
                        <?php
                            while (list($key, $val) = each($pd_name)){
                                if($row2[$key] != 0){
                                    if($prevCompany != $compArray[$key]){
                            ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $compArray[$key]; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                            <?php
                                        $prevCompany = $compArray[$key];
                                    }
                            ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $val ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row2[$key]; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php
                                    $count++;
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><?php echo $count; ?></td></tr>
            <?php   } ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: and yes i realize there are some bad practices (inline styles, etc), this is just a rough draft and i'll be cleaning everything later on.

Comment: Well, this is hard to say when we cannot see the result of the query. Are you sure there is multiple rows in $pd_name? Try to var_dump() it.

Comment: your bad practices make it harder for me to read the code and therefore harder for me to help you

Comment: what do you mean multiple rows in $pd_name? pd_name is just an array of the item name with it's key being it's column name in MYSQL. i'm not sure i understand what you mean.

Comment: I think, basically Gordon wants to know how many rows the first query returns.

Comment: ohh, many apologies! the first query returns around 30 rows, and it definitely works for the first row because the whole first row of the second while loop is outputted. it's just every row after that first row only the first 4 columns are shown correctly? why would the first row work perfectly and not the next ones?

Comment: Is `pd_col_name` unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

```
reset($pd_name);
while (list($key, $val) = each($pd_name))
```

The problem was that `each` steps through the array and once it reaches the end, it won't go any further. Therefore, you have to reset the array pointer to the beginning every time.